# C++14 uniform initialization on structs

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14, uniform-initialization

I've got the following fairly simple code:

```
    WNDCLASSEX windowClass = {0};

    windowClass.cbSize { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) };
```

I would like to know why the above code does not work and the code below does:

```
    WNDCLASSEX windowClass = {0};

    windowClass.cbSize = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) };
```

Visual Studio 15 2017 gives me those two errors:

> 1: expected a ';'
>
> 2: error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

Comment: That's assignment, not initialization. In C++, you use `=` to assign a value to a variable.

Comment: @Sneftel confusingly, you can also use `=` to initialize one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot initialize the same variable (windowClass) more than once and you cannot initialize the member variables in separate initialization statements.

In your case, since cbSize is the first item

```
WNDCLASSEX windowsClass { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) };
```

That will set cbSize to sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) and the rest of the struct to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Or why not go full c++?

```
struct WndClasssEx : WNDCLASSEX
{
    WndClassex() : WNDCLASSEX { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) } {}

}

auto mywndclass = WndClasssEx();
DoSomethingWindowsy(&mywndclass);
```

See c++ standard, section [Class] (quoted here from standard draft n4527, 2015).

specifically the note on standard-layout types:

> [ Note: Standard-layout classes are useful for communicating with code written in other programming languages.
>   Their layout is specified in 9.2. — end note ]

Comment: @AnT it's not a trick, it's perfectly valid c++ and is expressly allowed and well formed by the standard.

Comment: It is allowed. However, anyone using such tricks will quickly run into their limitations. E.g. while an `WndClasssEx *` can be used in place of `WNDCLASSEX *`, you won't be able to use an array or `WndClasssEx` where an array of `WNDCLASSEX` is expected. You won't be able to use a `WndClasssEx **` pointer where a `WNDCLASSEX **` pointer is expected. The applicability of this trick is very narrow, which is why it is just not worth it.

Comment: @AnT the standard specifically allows the array case. The technique is used throughout the WTL and ATL. Now I'm no fan of Microsoft coding practices, but they were correct in this case. There are limitations as you have mentioned. These are offset by the ability to ensure correctness through the c++ interface.

Comment: @RichardHodges: AnT is perfectly correct that the array case is disallowed in standard C++.  ATL takes advantages of many implementation-specific behaviors of the Microsoft C++ compiler that are not portable.

Comment: @BenVoigt can you cite the standard on this? My reading of it suggests that my MyWndClassEx struct is exactly the same, bit for bit as the base class, since they are PODs.

Comment: @RichardHodges: They are, up to the length of the base class.  But there is no guarantee that the size of the derived class isn't greater than its base class, and in fact the Standard explicitly calls out the possibility.  "If a standard-layout class object has any non-static data members, ... Otherwise, its address is the same as the address of its ﬁrst base class
subobject (if any). **[ Note: There might therefore be unnamed padding within a standard-layout struct object,
but not at its beginning ... ]**"

Comment: @BenVoigt fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

The first version "does not work" because it is syntactically nonsensical. There's no branch in C++ grammar that would be able to parse your first variant. The compiler simply has no idea what you are trying to say by that sequence of characters. So, the question is really to you: what did you try to achieve by that first version?

The second version works because it is valid C++ code. The `{ sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) }` on the right-hand side of assignment is interpreted as creation/initialization of a temporary object of the same type as `windowClass.cbSize`. That temporary object is then assigned to `windowClass.cbSize`. I.e., since `windowClass.cbSize` has `UINT` type, your second version is interpreted as

```
windowClass.cbSize = UINT{ sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) };
```

which in practice has the same effect as

```
windowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
```